# Aggregation and finding mode of data set

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am aggregating data and I cannot sum certain columns so I would like to take the most frequent observation from that column, or the mode value. Each ID can have only one site and number, so if there are ties then pick the smaller of the two numbers.

Example follows:

```
ID site  number

1  3     45

1  3     45

1  2     56

1  3     56

2  4     5

2  5     5

2  5     3

2  5     5
```

I want it to look like:

```
ID site  number

1  3     45

2  5     5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
with aggregation as
(
  select id
    , site
    , number
    , numberCount = count(1)
  from SiteNumbers
  group by id
    , site
    , number
), aggregateRanks as
(
  select *
    , idRank = row_number() over (partition by id order by numberCount desc, number, site)
  from aggregation
)
select id
  , site
  , number
from aggregateRanks
where idRank = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/33cad/2).

It matches your results, but depending on all your different cases might need some tweaking; hopefully it gives you some ideas.

Comment: You're welcome. If an answer solves your issue, please set it as the accepted answer, and if an answer is helpful, please upvote it. This lets users know they have helped you out and also rewards them for their efforts. You've asked over a dozen questions in quick succession and have exactly zero accepted answers and zero upvotes. Please consider how you're using this site and how to acknowledge people taking the effort to help you out.